# Responsive HTML page in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, responsive-design, response

I have a page that uses an `iframe` to call a responsive HTML page. It works, and when the browser size is reduced it gets scaled as well.

On the other hand, when I open it on a mobile device, the page is displayed but not responsive. It just shows the complete page in the `iframe`.

Here is my current code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe style='position:absolute;z-index:10;top:0;left:0;margin' width='100%' height='100%' scrolling='auto' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' align='top' frameborder='0' src='http://beautymakeupskincare.com/usoneoff/indexpro7.html' /></iframe> 
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it? Here is the [link](http://nuwavenaturals.com:8080/shop-us/ps.php)

Comment: Out of annoyance of your spam warning message on the link I'm walking away

Comment: try this 
http://nuwavenaturals.com/shop-us/ps.php

its not spam , im using port 8080 to bypass varnsih, never mind

Comment: i am freelancer working on these pages, for some product presale, its not spam for me but work